# Validation of form layouts in ngx-admin angular project

Tags: angular, firebase, nebular, ngx-admin

With the help of forms of ngx-admin/forms/form layout. I made my own form. Now I want to apply validation to the form and send data to firebase. I tried using formgroup, ngmodel. Nothing works. Help me out.

This is the link for formlayout - https://www.akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/forms/layouts

I had downloaded the template from here - https://akveo.github.io/ngx-admin/

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>Appointment form</nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>

    <form class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-control-group">
          <label for="title" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <nb-select selected="1" id="title">
              <nb-option value="1">Select</nb-option>
              <nb-option value="2">Mr.</nb-option>
              <nb-option value="3">Mrs.</nb-option>
              <nb-option value="4">Ms</nb-option>
            </nb-select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fname" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input 
              type="text" nbInput fullWidth id="fname" placeholder="First Name" 
              required/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="mname" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Middle Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth id="mname" placeholder="Middle Name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="lname" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="email" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" nbInput fullWidth id="lname" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="adrss" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea rows="5" id="adrss" nbInput fullWidth shape="round"  placeholder="Address"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="doctor" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Referred By</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <nb-select selected="1" id="doctor">
              <nb-option value="1">Select</nb-option>
              <nb-option value="2">Dr. Abc</nb-option>
              <nb-option value="3">Dr. Xyz</nb-option>
              <nb-option value="4">Dr. Lmn</nb-option>
            </nb-select>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" nbButton status="warning">Book Appointment</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    </form>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Comment: When you say *send data to firebase*, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Actually i wanted to send the form data to particular mail id. So created a  project at console.firebase, created a database, and save data in it. I'll write a function to send mail and i will be fetching the data from database

Comment: I took the reference of this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-4IxaH7yFE&list=PLx-q4INfd95EDZlNka9WicLOlVhXpRbXB&index=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an exemple of how to use reactive forms: 
first you must import **ReactiveFormsModule** from angular/forms in your module
then you can use **formGroup** Directive and the **formControlName** input provided by the **FormControlName** directive to bind each of you inputs.
check:  https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Yeah, it worked. All the time i was implementing part of it and worrying about the errors