# Add various fields in the text section of nodemailer

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm sending mail from my angular app using nodemailer. I have a variable which has several attributes like `firstname`, `middlename`, `email`, `mobile`, `address`. I'm fetching this data from firebase and each variable can be accessed by writing `$data.firstname`, `$data.email`. I was able to send only 1 variable right now. I want to send all the variables to the mail with labels

So mail content should be

- Email - abc@123
- First Name - ABC
- Address - LMN
- Mobile - 7777777777

Please help me out.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
admin.initializeApp()
require('dotenv').config()


const {SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASS} = process.env;

exports.sendMailNotification1=functions.firestore.document('submissions/{docID}')
.onCreate((snap, ctx)=> {
    const data=snap.data();

    let authData=nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure:true,
        auth:{
            user: SENDER_EMAIL,
            pass: SENDER_PASS
        }
    });
    authData.sendMail({
        from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Appointment Info ',
        text:`${data.fname}`,
        html:`${data.email}`,
    }).then(res=>console.log('Succesfully Sent')).catch(err=> console.log(err)
    );
})
```

Comment: not sure I understand, but do you have a contact form for a user to enter those data?

Comment: yeah i have a form, user enters the data. I should send that data to some X person's mail. So I was doing this with the help of nodemailer.First i send the form data to firebase and with the help above function sendEmailNotification, I'm sending the mail. Problem is I can only send 1 variable. `$data.email`. But I want to send all the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the NodeMailer [doc](https://nodemailer.com/message/), you can choose between:

using the `message`'s `text` element for sending "the plaintext version of the message"

OR

using the `message`'s `html` element for sending "the HTML version of the message".

---

So for example, if you use the HTML option you could use an HTML list as follows:

```
//...
const htmlContent = `<ul><li>Email - ${data.email}</li><li>Address - ${data.address}</li></ul>`;

return authData.sendMail({
        from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Appointment Info',
        html: htmlContent
    })
.then(res => {
       console.log('Succesfully Sent');
       return null;
})
.catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
       return null;
});
```

---

Note the addition of several `return`s in the code, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions for more info on this key aspect.

Comment: Could you please help me with this question too.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577545/validation-of-form-layouts-in-ngx-admin-angular-project?noredirect=1#comment107171670_60577545